# Why is my Swing application minimizing when I create a dialog?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a simple Swing application which runs in full screen mode. My application instantiates a `JFrame`, which in turn instantiates a `JPanel`, where all of the drawing is done in the `paintComponent` method. I also have a `MouseListener` watching for certain events.

One of those events (clicking on a certain area of the screen) triggers a prompt. Here is my code to show the prompt (keep in mind this comes from within my class that is extending `JPanel`).

```
int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Quit?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if ( choice == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION ) {
    dialogOpen = false;
    System.exit(0);
} else {
    dialogOpen = false;
    repaint();
}
```

The only trouble is... as soon as this code runs, the entire window disappears. More specifically, it looks like it minimizes itself, because I can click on the Java icon in the taskbar and it pops right back up. But how do I stop it from minimizing itself? All I want to do is display a simple prompt!

Comment: Is the popup not displaying at all? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Does the app minimize When the app starts? Or does it minimize when NO is selected from `JOptionPane`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: By "runs in full screen mode" do you mean that you're passing your JFrame to [GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow-java.awt.Window-), or do you mean mean that you're calling [setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-) on your JFrame?

Comment: @VGR I mean GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow

Comment: @Max no errors, but if I restore the window after it disappears (by clicking its icon on the Windows taskbar) then the pop-up is there.

Comment: @S1LENTWARRIOR no, the app starts full screen like you would expect. And selecting NO does not cause it to minimize

Comment: Can this problem be because the DialogBox gets on "top" of the maximized frame and force the full screen frame to minimize?

Comment: @Mnemonics that seems very plausible! What can I do to handle that more gracefully?

Comment: Full Screen Exclusive mode guarantees one thing, that there is only ONE active window on the screen, the moment you show another Window, the OS needs to drop out of FSEM in order to show it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks to everyone for their helpful comments (what is it with people and commenting here, by the way? how come people write everything that could go in an answer in the comments instead?)

Rather than calling `.showConfirmDialog(this, ...)` (where `this` is my `JPanel` subclass), I needed to call `.showConfirmDialog(parent, ...)` (where `parent` is my `JFrame` subclass). Then, I added a `WindowStateListener` on the `JFrame` to detect state changes and reset the window state.